# Wifi device is not showing up in device manager after installing windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, wifi-driver

Hi I have an Asus x55A laptop. My wifi was working fine till I installed new windows and now I am unable to see the device for wifi. I have installed other drivers like HD graphics etc. But ther's no wifi my device manager is neither showing installed nor not-installed drivers in. Could someone help what reason it could be to hide the device all of a sudden just after installing new windows

Comment: There's no unknown device in Device Manager? Which OS did you have earlier? Does the laptop have a physical switch to turn WiFi on/off?

Comment: There's no unknown device in device manager. I had windows 8 before then I installed windows 7 and it was missing and then I reinstall windows 8 and still missing :( to turn on/off it has Fn+F2 which is not doing anything

Comment: Are you sure you've installed *all* the Win8 64-bit drivers for your model?

Comment: Yes i did but my problem is i can't even see unknown device in the device manager ? i am afraid it's hardware problem..

Comment: If you suspect that's the case then time to take it in for a check-up...

Comment: Or to confirm that by reinstalling the old OS.

Comment: Its possible that windows installed a Generic Driver that took over the wifi card I had this issue once.

Comment: Another Idea i had was turn the laptop off unplug your wireless card. Then turn it on and off again re plug it back on and see if it shows up.